# Jupyter Notebook nbconvert without magic commands/ w/o markdown

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I have a `Jupyter` notebook and I'd like to convert it into a `Python` script using the `nbconvert` command from *within* the `Jupyter` notebook.

I have included the following line at the end of the notebook:

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to script <filename>.ipynb
```

This creates a `Python` script. However, I'd like the resulting `.py` file to have the following properties:

1. No input statements, such as:

   > # In[27]:
2. No markdown, including statements such as:

   > # coding: utf-8
3. Ignore `%magic` commands such as:

   1. `%matplotlib inline`
   2. `!jupyter nbconvert --to script <filename>.ipynb`, i.e. the command within the notebook that executes the `Python` conversion

   Currently, the `%magic` commands get translated to the form: `get_ipython().magic(...)`, but these are not necessarily recognized in `Python`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to get control of what appears in the output is to tag the cells that you don't want in the output and then use the TagRemovePreprocessor to remove the cells.

[image]

The code below also uses the exclude_markdown function in the TemplateExporter to remove markdown.

```
!jupyter nbconvert \
    --TagRemovePreprocessor.enabled=True \
    --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags="['parameters']" \
    --TemplateExporter.exclude_markdown=True \
    --to python "notebook_with_parameters_removed.ipynb"
```

To remove the commented lines and the input statement markets (like # [1]), I believe you'll need to post-process the Python file with something like the following in the cell after the cell you call !jupyter nbconvert from (note that this is Python 3 code):

```
import re
from pathlib import Path
filename = Path.cwd() / 'notebook_with_parameters_removed.py'
code_text = filename.read_text().split('\n')
lines = [line for line in code_text if len(line) == 0 or 
        (line[0] != '#' and 'get_ipython()' not in line)]
clean_code = '\n'.join(lines)
clean_code = re.sub(r'\n{2,}', '\n\n', clean_code)
filename.write_text(clean_code.strip())
```

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious solution seems to work for me:

```sh
 jupyter nbconvert --to python a_notebook.ipynb --stdout | grep -v -e "^get_ipython" | python
```

Of course, you can't use something like `dirs = !ls` in your notebooks for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this will spare people from wasting 2 hours trying to use `nbconvert` template structure. This is what did the job for me:

```
nbconvert --to python --RegexRemovePreprocessor.patterns="^%" analysis.ipynb
```

Comment: Better regex: --RegexRemovePreprocessor.patterns="^[!%]", this will also remove lines starting with "!".

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT - 27 November 2023**

The [Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) plugin for Jupyter (notebook and lab) is an excellent solution for converting notebooks to pure python. Jupytext builds and maintains a near live connection between `.ipynb` and `.py` files. Editing one results in updates made to the other.

This makes it trivial to pull changes in from collaborators that work in either the notebook or flat text files. The *cleanest* solution is to ask Jupytext to use the "light" format when converting Notebooks to python. The default is to use the "percent" format which surrounds the plain-text version of notebook code from each cell with `# %%`. This is a bit ugly to read if you're looking for a "clean" output.

This solution should also exclude Markdown from the `.py` files.

To default to the *light*. format, create a `jupytext.toml` file in the root of your project and adding the following line:

`jupytext.toml`:

```py
formats = "ipynb,py:light"
```

To include a shebang line on the first line of the `.py` file, add the following line somewhere in your notebook (e.g. last cell). Run this once -- you may need to delete the `.py` to handle the out-of-sync changes this causes.

```py
!jupytext YourNotebookNameHere.ipynb --update-metadata '{"jupytext":{"executable":"/usr/bin/env python"}}' --to py
```

**Also a good solution, but dated**

*I've been struggling to get the nbconvert module to install reliably under python 3.11 on all platforms. Because of this, I've moved to [Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) (see above)*

Jupyter nbconvert has made this a little bit easier with a new [template structure](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html).

Templates should be placed in the template path. This can be found by running `jupyter --paths`

Each template should be placed in its own directory within the template directory and must contain a conf.json and index.py.j2 file.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64144224/5530152) covers all the details for adding a template.

This template will remove all the of the markdown, magic and cell numbers leaving a "runnable" .py file. Run this template from within a notebook with `!jupyter nbconvert --to python --template my_clean_python_template my_notebook.ipynb`

**`index.py.j2`**

```
{%- extends 'null.j2' -%}

## set to python3
{%- block header -%}
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8
{% endblock header %}

## remove cell counts entirely
{% block in_prompt %}
{% if resources.global_content_filter.include_input_prompt -%}
{% endif %}
{% endblock in_prompt %}

## remove markdown cells entirely
{% block markdowncell %}
{% endblock markdowncell %}

{% block input %}
{{ cell.source | ipython2python }}
{% endblock input %}


## remove magic statement completely
{% block codecell %}
{{'' if "get_ipython" in super() else super() }}
{% endblock codecell%}
```

Comment: People say those templates stopped working in new versions of `nbconvert`, see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3707/.

Comment: @krvkir: Can you be more specific? The link you provided is almost a year old. This solution appears to work for nbconvert > 6.0. This is what I'm using in 6.2.0 and 6.1.7 across several platforms and it appears to be OK. I haven't tried it with 6.3.0 yet. The entire structure of the templates have changed between V5 and V6. Check this solution for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64144224/5530152

Comment: My bad, I overlooked that your solution is for the new template system. Sorry for misinformation.