# What is the proper way to specify a custom template path for jupyter nbconvert V6?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

What is the proper way to specify a custom template path for nbconvert?

Under nbonvert version 6, templates are now a directory with several files. Those templates can live in any number of locations depending on the platform.

Raspbian:

```
['/home/pi/.local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates', '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates', '/usr/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates']
```

OS X with Pyenv:

```
['/Users/ac/Library/Jupyter/nbconvert/templates', '/Users/ac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates', '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates', '/usr/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates']
```

I'm trying to sync my templates over several different platforms and would like to specify a custom location.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137110/right-place-to-put-custom-nbconvert-templates) from 2 years ago seems correct, but appears to apply to V5 of nbconvert -- the method has changed names from `template_path` to `template_paths`.

I've tried the solution suggested in the link above using a template that I know works when placed in one of the known locations. I end up with this error when trying to specify a custom location as suggested:

`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: null.j2`

I suspect that by setting the path to `/path/to/.jupyter/templates/my_template/`, I completely override all the other template locations and lose the `null.j2` template that my template extends. I've included my template at the end on the off chance it has some errors that are causing this.

[The docs for V6 config files](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html) are not much help either:

```
TemplateExporter.template_paths : List
   Default: ['.']

   No description
```

and

```
PythonExporter.template_paths : List
   Default: ['.']

   No description
```

There's a [long thread from May 2019](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/pull/1028) discussing this on the Git Repo, but I can't quite make sense of what the ultimate conclusion was.

My custom Python template:

```
{%- extends 'null.j2' -%}

## set to python3
{%- block header -%}
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8
{% endblock header %}

## remove cell counts entirely
{% block in_prompt %}
{% if resources.global_content_filter.include_input_prompt -%}
{% endif %}
{% endblock in_prompt %}

## remove markdown cells entirely
{% block markdowncell %}
{% endblock markdowncell %}

{% block input %}
{{ cell.source | ipython2python }}
{% endblock input %}


## remove magic statement completely
{% block codecell %}
{{'' if "get_ipython" in super() else super() }}
{% endblock codecell%}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Issue #1428 on the Git Repo](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1428) contains the basis for this solution.

From scratch/recent upgrade from v5 to v6 do the following:

1. Generate a current and up-to-date configuration file for V6 in `~/.jupyter`

```
$ jupyter nbconvert --generate-config
```

2. Edit the configuration file `~/.jupyter/jupyter_nbconvert_config.py` to add the following lines:

```
from pathlib import Path
# set a custom path for templates in 
c.TemplateExporter.extra_template_basedirs
my_templates = Path('~/my/custom/templates').expanduser().absolute()
# add the custom path to the extra_template_basedirs
c.TemplateExporter.extra_template_basedirs = [my_templates]
```

3. Add templates to the `~/my/custom/templates` directory

   - Each template must be in its own sub directory (`/my/custom/templates/foo_template`)
   - Each template must contain a [`conf.json`](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html#the-content-of-nbconvert-templates) and `index.py.j2` file. the index is the actual template. See below for an example
4. run nbconvert:

```
$ jupyter nbconvert --to python --template my_custom_template foo.ipynb
```

**`conf.json` Basic Example**

```
{
    "base_template": "base",
    "mimetypes": {
        "text/x-python": true
    }
}
```

**`index.py.j2` Example**

```
{%- extends 'null.j2' -%}

## set to python3
{%- block header -%}
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8
{% endblock header %}

## remove cell counts entirely
{% block in_prompt %}
{% if resources.global_content_filter.include_input_prompt -%}
{% endif %}
{% endblock in_prompt %}

## remove markdown cells entirely
{% block markdowncell %}
{% endblock markdowncell %}

{% block input %}
{{ cell.source | ipython2python }}
{% endblock input %}


## remove magic statement completely
{% block codecell %}
{{'' if "get_ipython" in super() else super() }}
```

Comment: I presume you mean `jupyter nbconvert --generate-config`? Your first line just creates a default notebook config file. Also, this doesn't work on my end. Still get the same error message: "No template sub-directory with name 'lab' found in the following paths:" and the paths listed are the same as prior to implementing the above fix

Comment: @johnnybarrels You are correct. I've fixed the instructions. It was indeed the intention to create a clean, default configuration file to get started with. Do you have a single template in sub directory under "lab" that includes an .json and .j2 file?