# How to resolve TemplateNotFound error when upgrading nbconvert to 6.x+?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

When trying to make a new Jupyter-based presentation using a template I've used in the past, I found that when `nbconvert` is upgraded past 6.0, I get an error related to a missing built-in template `basic.tpl`. A minimal reproducer for this, create a template file called `custom.tpl`:

```
{% extends 'basic.tpl' %}
```

Then take any Jupyter notebook and `pip install jupyter nbconvert` and run `nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to=slides --template=custom.tpl`. You'll get an exception like this:

```
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook example.ipynb to slides
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp.niaMlxSIbz/venv/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
...
  File "/tmp/tmp.niaMlxSIbz/custom.tpl", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'basic.tpl' %}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: basic.tpl
```

If you `pip install 'nbconvert < 6.0'`, you'll find that the same command succeeds.

I imagine this is related to the [changes to how templates work that came in 6.0](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id12), but I believe that `.tpl` templates are still intended to be supported, and there is even a listed [PR that restores the basic template](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/pull/1431), but I can find no instructions anywhere on how to update my template with references to the new location.

Is there some way to fix this by changing the reference to `'basic.tpl'`?

Pinning to 5.6.1 "works", but version 5.6.1 of `nbconvert` doesn't work with Python 3.9, and I need access to some of the newer Python features in my notebook.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a direct backwards compatibility for `.tpl` files, but you can migrate your template directives into a the new template directory format.

Use `jupyter --paths` to find your user (or system) jupyter config paths. From there, you can add custom templates into the templates directory.

```
$ jupyter --paths                                                 (master) ✓
config:
    /Users/txoof/.jupyter << user templates can be found here on my system
    /Users/txoof/.local/share/virtualenvs/folderAudit-FJk3azd9/etc/jupyter << jupyter default templates can be found here
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter  
    /etc/jupyter
```

I had success by copying one of the default system templates into my user template directory and pasting my directives from my .tpl files into the `index.py.j2` file.

You can find more details for migrating from nbconvert 5 to 6 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64127278/what-is-the-proper-way-to-specify-a-custom-template-path-for-jupyter-nbconvert-v/64144224#64144224).

The documentation for moving from 5 to 6 is pretty awful as of November of 2020, but the [nbconvert issues at github](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues) are pretty active and helpful.